# EditText.setText("some string") don't work

Tags: android-edittext, settext

I searched following issue in this site and found many suggestions, 
but any solution don't solve my issue.
If anybody knows real solution, please guide me.
Thank you in advance !!!

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

```
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Intent localIntent;

    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;

    switch(requestCode){

        case SEARCH_ADDRESS_ACTIVITY :

            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                final String address = data.getExtras().getString("data");
                if (address != null) {
                    addressEditText.setText(address);


                }
            }
            break;
```

:::::

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry.

In my case, I cannot see the text because of EditText's height is so narrow.

The EditText's hint got space(height) more, so the EditText area was not seen ;;;